# local notification only work on the starting page in phone-gap android

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am using local notification plugin 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
and it work just fine when the notification is in the starting page when i navigate from the main page to another page the notification in the new page doesn't work i tried to make the second page the starting page and the notification worked just fine

Here is the code for notification it get date from web service

```
$.ajax({
    url: "mywebservicelink",
    data: {
        Name: name,
        Gender: gender,
        BirthDate: birthdate,
        BirthHour: birthhour,
        BirthPlace: birthplace,
        DoctorName: doctorname,
        disease: disease,
        allergy: allergies,
        OtherMedicalCondititon: others,
        PID: MumId,
        img: img
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(response) {
        $(response).find("childvacineinfo").each(function(index) {
            var Vaccinedate = $(this).find("VaccineDate").text();
            y = parseInt(Vaccinedate.substring(0, 4));
            m = parseInt(Vaccinedate.substring(5, 7));
            d = parseInt(Vaccinedate.substring(8, 10));
            u = parseInt(Vaccinedate.substring(14, 16));
            da = Vaccinedate.substring(0, 10);
            dat = new Date();
            dat.setYear(y);
            dat.setMonth(m - 1);
            dat.setDate(d);
            dat.setHours(11, u + 50, 00, 00);
            alert(y + ":" + m + ":" + d + ":" + u);
            var ParentName = $(this).find("ParentName").text();
            var ChildName = $(this).find("ChildName").text();
            var VaccineName = $(this).find("VaccineName").text();
            window.plugin.notification.local.add({
                id: index,
                title: 'index',
                date: dat,
                //date of vac
                message: "vaccine"
                autoCancel: true,
                sound: 'android.resource://com.alia.workshop/raw/a'
            });
            window.plugin.notification.local.onclick = function(index, state, json) {
                localStorage.setItem("date", dat);
                window.location.replace("New.html");
            };
        });
        window.location.assign("~/ParentProfile.html");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("nooo");
    }
});
```

Comment: are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: no iam not using jquery mobile